# How to create curvy corner for a HTML table ? *That should be compatible in IE6*

Tags: html, internet-explorer-6, curvycorners

I've a HTML table, i want to make its corners as curvy corners. I've tried but its working only in ff, chrome but not in IE6. I want it to be compatible in different versions of IE. Somebody please tell me how to make it compatible in IE6+?

Comment: "I've tried"... *what* have you tried? I'm assuming `border-radius`, but it would be useful if you clarified what you've tried and maybe even showed some code.

Comment: yes, i've used border-radius but that is not working..

Comment: May I ask why you want to support IE6?  Does your IE user base lean heavily towards 6?

Answer (score 0):

`Border-radius` is not something that is supported in earlier versions of IE.

However, you can use something like **CSS3 Pie** to make it work out.

http://css3pie.com